# Set Spinner selection programmatically

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an issue in setting the spinner selection. Here is what I am doing:
I have an XML in which I have a button and a spinner that is populated with country names. I have not used adapter to populate the spinner instead I have named an array in the string file in the values folder which has a lot of items as country names. Now on selecting a country lets say I select England  and click on the button. On clicking a new activity is to start which also has a spinner which is populated with the same list in the same way. But what I want is that the second activity spinner should be showing the selected country that was England in this case as the current item in the spinner.
But I can't solve it.
Here is piece of code to what I have done

//First activity XML

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/spinner1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:entries="@array/sehirler"
   android:prompt="@string/sehirsec" />
```

//Second activity XML

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/spinner2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:entries="@array/sehirler"
   android:prompt="@string/sehirsec" />
```

//Firstactivity code

```
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        spinnerItem = spinner .getSelectedItem().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(firstactivity.this, secondactivty.class); 
        intent.putExtra("name", spinnerItem);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

//Second Activity Code

```
sehir = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name2 = intent.getExtras().getString("name");

sehir.setSelection(getIndex(sehir, name2));

private int getIndex(Spinner spinner, String myString) {
    int index = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<spinner.getCount();i++) {
        if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals(myString)) {
           index = i;
        }
    }
        return index;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried your code and it works fine with me all the way to Gingerbread. When you create the method "private int getIndex(Spinner spinner etc..." you're creating the method outside of onCreate...right?

Comment: Yes outside onCreate. Did i work fine for you?

Comment: Yes it worked for me, could you post your full code, or private message me

Comment: PM me please I don't know how to do it lol

Comment: email me andrewelmasry@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your spinner2 is not in the second activity but in a completely different layout. Check and see if you have an adapter. If you have a custom adapter, then you have to pass that value of position to the constructor of your custom adapter.

In your second activity, pass the position value to the CustomAdapter constructor:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);

CustomAdapter jsonCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(SecondActivity.this, list, position);
```

In your CustomAdapter, set it up like this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ItemObject> list;
    private int spinnerPosition;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> list, int position) {
        inflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.list = list;
        spinnerPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder listViewHolder;
        if(convertView == null){
            listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
            listViewHolder.spinner = (Spinner)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
        } else {
           listViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        listViewHolder.spinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        Spinner spinner;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same thing? I was finding index via a function made outside onCreate that you did within

Comment: I figured out the problem, your spinner2 is not in the second activity but in a completely different layout in your custom adapter, therefore you have to pass position to the constructor of your custom adapter. i will edit my answer for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Please rate my question too